# How do I have a timer that changes a Label every second? Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit, xcode6

I made an NSTimer and I made it run a method every second that had a integer that added one each time and put in into a SKLabelNode but it never changes. Here's the code. (Sorry if I made it confusing)

```
> #import "GameScene.h"
> 
> @implementation GameScene
> 
> -(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
>     /* Setup your scene here */
>     
>     [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1
>                                     target:self
>                                     selector:@selector(timerMethod)
>                                     userInfo:nil
>                                     repeats:YES];
>     
>     timeAlive = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Arial"];
>     timeAlive.text = @"Time Alive: 0 Seconds";
>     timeAlive.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
>     
>     character = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Character"];
>     character.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)/2 - 150, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)/2);
>     
>     enemy = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Character"];
>     enemy.name = @"enemy";
>     enemy.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)/2);
>     
>     [self addChild:timeAlive];
>     
>     [self addChild:character];
>     [self addChild:enemy];
>      }
> 
> -(void) timerMethod{
>     
>     timeAlive.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
>     timeAliveString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time Alive: %d Seconds", timeAliveInt];
>     //timeAliveString = [@(timeAliveInt) stringValue];
>     timeAlive.text = timeAliveString;
>     timeAliveInt = 1;
>      }
> 
> -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
>     /* Called when a touch begins */
>     
>     for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
>         CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
>         
>         
>         
>     } }
> 
> -(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
>     /* Called before each frame is rendered */ }
> 
> @end
```

(I defined the variables in the Header class)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You want `scheduledTimerWithInterval` instead of `timerWithTimeInterval`. That, along with retaining a reference to the timer you create, should fix your problem.

Comment: ah dang, I miss typed that line of code. I feel like an idiot now. Thank you!!

Comment: haha, ok I did :D I don't have enough rep to upvote but someone disliked it D:

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `NSTimer` in SpriteKit. They don't work well with SpriteKit. For example the NSTimer will not be automatically paused when setting the `paused` property of the `SKScene`.  You can SKActions instead.

```
SKAction *waitAction = [SKAction waitForDuration:1];
SKAction *callTimerAction = [SKAction runBlock:^{
    [self timerMethod];
}];

SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[callTimerAction, waitAction]];
SKAction *foreverRepeatSequence = [SKAction repeatActionForever:sequence];

[self runAction:foreverRepeatSequence];
```